# How to reinstall yum?

Tags: yum

I made a big mistake: I removed yum. So now when I for example run the following it gives me an error:

```
$ yum clean all
yum command not found.
```

I can download the package succesfully:

```
wget mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/i386/Packages/yum-3.2.29-40.el6.centos.noarch.rpm
--2014-01-15 15:42:59--  http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/i386/Packages/yum-3.2.29-40.el6.centos.noarch.rpm
Resolving mirror.centos.org... 192.133.139.3
Connecting to mirror.centos.org|192.133.139.3|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1019540 (996K) [application/x-rpm]
Saving to: “yum-3.2.29-40.el6.centos.noarch.rpm.1”

100%[====================================================================================================================>] 1,019,540    649K/s   in 1.5s

2014-01-15 15:43:01 (649 KB/s) - “yum-3.2.29-40.el6.centos.noarch.rpm.1” saved [1019540/1019540]
```

Trying to install the downloaded package gives the following error:

```
# rpm -ivh yum-3.2.29-40.el6.centos.noarch.rpm
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
    file /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/yum/__init__.py from install of yum-3.2.29-40.el6.centos.noarch conflicts with file from package yum-3.2.29-30.el6.centos.noarch
[...]
file /usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.pyo from install of yum-3.2.29-40.el6.centos.noarch conflicts with file from package yum-3.2.29-30.el6.centos.noarch
```

There is no directory "yum" in `/usr/bin`.

When I use the command "rpm -qa | grep yum".

```
yum-metadata-parser-1.1.2-16.el6.x86_64
yum-plugin-fastestmirror-1.1.30-14.el6.noarch
yum-3.2.29-30.el6.centos.noarch
```

The distro is CentOS 6.3.
How can I reinstall yum?

Comment: you have the exact same problem as with your ftp issue the `$PATH` of your computer is f$$$$ up. please give us the content of command `echo $PATH`  if you work as `root` please connect to `root` account with the command `su -` and not `su`

Answer (score 8):

Given you already have `yum` installed you cannot do a `rpm -ivh ..`. This command will install an RPM that hasn't been installed yet. Instead you should use either `rpm -Uvh ...` to upgrade the `yum` package or remove it first, `rpm -e yum`.

I would suggest doing an upgrade on the package.

```
$ wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/i386/Packages/yum-3.2.29-40.el6.centos.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh yum-3.2.29-40.el6.centos.noarch.rpm
```

#### Relying on the package manager

RPM can help you fix issues like this, or at the very least, help to identify issues. The `rpm` command includes the ability to verify the packages it maintains.

```
 $ rpm -V yum
```

If there isn't an issue it will simply return nothing. If there are issues it will tell you which files are at fault.

```
$ rpm -V httpd
SM5....T  c /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

The letters/numbers tell you about various aspects of the package which are out of specification with what was originally installed.

*excerpt from rpm man page*

> Each of the 9 characters denotes the result of a comparison of attribute(s) of the file to the  value  of those  attribute(s) recorded in the database.  A single "." (period) means the test passed, while a single "?" (question mark) indicates the test could not be performed (e.g. file permissions prevent reading). Otherwise, the (mnemonically emBoldened) character denotes failure of the corresponding `--verify` test:
>
> ```
>    S file Size differs
>    M Mode differs (includes permissions and file type)
>    5 digest (formerly MD5 sum) differs
>    D Device major/minor number mismatch
>    L readLink(2) path mismatch
>    U User ownership differs
>    G Group ownership differs
>    T mTime differs
>    P caPabilities differ
> ```

Comment: @az93 - terrific! Glad that solved your issue. Please mark this A as accepted so other's know your issue's been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Download yum (no idea what distro you are using) you can try from [here](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=yum&submit=Search+...)  and then install the pkg with

```
rpm -ivh <rpm_file_name>
```

or check out the yum project [page](http://yum.baseurl.org). For example, for `yum` 3.2.29-40 (32bit):

```
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/i386/Packages/yum-3.2.29-40.el6.centos.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh yum-3.2.29-40.el6.centos.noarch.rpm –
```

Comment: How can I know which version of CentOS im using (i using PuTTy)

Comment: @az93 `cat /etc/redhat-release` should show you the version.

Comment: OK thx, this is CentOS release 6.3

Comment: Can you give me exactly the command. Thx

Comment: wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/i386/Packages/yum-3.2.29-40.el6.centos.noarch.rpm ; rpm -ivh yum-3.2.29-40.el6.centos.noarch.rpm

Comment: I still got the same problem : yum command not found... I don't understand.

Comment: The link is not valid.

Comment: @az93 please [edit] your question to add the command you just ran (`rpm -ivh yum...`) and its output.

Comment: please share the output of rpm -qa | grep yum

Comment: yum-metadata-parser-1.1.2-16.el6.x86_64
yum-plugin-fastestmirror-1.1.30-14.el6.noarch
yum-3.2.29-30.el6.centos.noarch

Comment: How did you remove yum? It looks like the old pkg is still installed. You can try to upgrade the pkg with rpm -Uvh yum-3.2.29-40.el6.centos.noarch.rpm

Comment: http://vault.centos.org/5.11/os/x86_64/CentOS/yum-3.2.22-40.el5.centos.noarch.rpm

Answer (score 0):

Here I’m listing the steps to resolve this problem. Execute the following YUM command for that.

1. Eliminate all of the header files which yum uses for dependency
   resolution.

   ```
   # yum clean headers
   ```
2. Remove all of the packages held in the caches

   ```
   # yum clean packages
   ```
3. Remove all metadata

   ```
   # yum clean metadata
   ```
4. Clean dbcache

   ```
   # yum clean dbcache
   ```
5. Clean all

   ```
   # yum clean all
   ```

Run the update command, if all of the above mentioned commands didn’t solve the issue.

```
# yum -y update
```

If yum update failed it may be due to the corruption in RPM database under /var/lib/rpm/ location. Please do follow the below pasted steps to resolve the issue.

```
# rm -f /var/lib/rpm/__db.*
# rpm -vv –rebuilddb
# yum update
```

That’s it.

**Source**: [[Solved] The server’s system package manager, ‘YUM’, failed : Error with easyapache](http://www.crybit.com/solved-the-servers-system-package-manager-yum-failed/)